I am getting Errors after upgrading Flutter v3.24.0
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/skeletons-0.0.3/lib/src/widgets.dart:56:42: Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
                color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/skeletons-0.0.3/lib/src/widgets.dart:100:46: Error: The getter 'backgroundColor' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
 - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'backgroundColor'.
                    color: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/element_widget.dart:109:5: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderChartElementLayoutBuilder<T, D>'.
 - 'RenderChartElementLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/src/charts/common/element_widget.dart' ('../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/element_widget.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
    markNeedsBuild();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/core_legend.dart:452:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder<Constraints, RenderObject>'.
 - 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
 - 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
        renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/base.dart:3085:7: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderLoadingIndicator'.
 - 'RenderLoadingIndicator' is from 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/src/charts/base.dart' ('../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/base.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
      markNeedsBuild();
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/common/core_tooltip.dart:168:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder<Constraints, RenderObject>'.
 - 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
 - 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
        renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/syncfusion_flutter_charts-24.2.9/lib/src/charts/cartesian_chart.dart:1330:22: Error: The method 'markNeedsBuild' isn't defined for the class 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder<Constraints, RenderObject>'.
 - 'RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart').
 - 'Constraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
 - 'RenderObject' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' ('../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/object.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'markNeedsBuild'.
        renderObject.markNeedsBuild();
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/carousel_slider-4.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:9:1: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart'.
import 'carousel_controller.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/carousel_slider-4.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:48:15: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart'.
            : CarouselController() as CarouselControllerImpl,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/carousel_slider-4.2.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:62:15: Error: 'CarouselController' is imported from both 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_controller.dart' and 'package:flutter/src/material/carousel.dart'.
            : CarouselController() as CarouselControllerImpl,
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot_program failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/wz-application-team/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 3:

User cancelled
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun devicectl list devices --timeout 5 --json-output /var/folders/z1/zvvw39q93d92mfnlxm3d6v5c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.qmW9pv/core_devices.8jUzf4/core_device_list.json
Error executing devicectl: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally with exit code 3:

User cancelled
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun devicectl list devices --timeout 5 --json-output /var/folders/z1/zvvw39q93d92mfnlxm3d6v5c0000gn/T/flutter_tools.qmW9pv/core_devices.cdBh0Y/core_device_list.json

I have tried pub cache clean and all other commands.

Which packages do you use in pubspec.yaml?

using syncfusion is a part source of this problem, check that answer

try to use dart pub cache repair

The reported issue arises because the Flutter SDK was upgraded to version 3.24.0 on August 6, 2024, while the chart packages are currently compatible only with Flutter SDK version 3.22.3. The team has begun evaluating the compatibility and feasibility of updating the packages to work with the latest Flutter version, 3.24.0. In the meantime, we can use Flutter SDK version 3.22.3 when working with the syncfusion_flutter_charts package.

When I upgraded to version ^5.0.0 of the carousel_slider package, the error was resolved.

Check your dependencies that have to do with UI, in my case it was Skeletons, which has conflicts with the theme. Detect which UI library has the problem and update it.

add the whole package to your workspace by finding it in your folders in the pub cache and drag it to the project, choose copy folder, replace in pubspec.yaml:
syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^26.2.11 by this:
 syncfusion_flutter_charts:
    path: ./syncfusion_flutter_charts-26.2.11/

and change all appearances of markNeedsBuild by markNeedsLayout and run your project.

There is a compatability issue with latest flutter versions with skeletons 0.0.3 library, the workaround is to replace the line
Theme.of(context).backgroundColor
with
Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
in
%AppData%/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/skeletons-0.0.3/lib/src/widgets.dart
(or equivalent file on your OS)
in 2 places
line 56 and line 100
will have to do it until someone fixes and updates the references to the skeletons library

Create
markNeedsBuild(){} 

in abstract class RenderObject with
DiagnosticableTreeMixin implements HitTestTarget {    
}



Please avoid images of code.
